# Standard way to handle quoted symbol in lisp macros in Scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp, lisp-macros

For some code I was working I've needed to handle 'x inside macro. What is standard way of handling those values?

I have code like this:

```
(define (quoted-symbol? x)
   (and (pair? x) (eq? (car x) 'quote) (symbol? (cadr x)) (null? (cddr x))))

(define-macro (test x)
   (if (quoted-symbol? x)
      `(begin
          (display ',(cadr x))
          (newline))))

(test 'hello) ;; 'hello will be expanded into list (quote hello)
```

Is this how this should be handled, or is just in macro you don't use quoted symbols?

**NOTE**: I'm not asking about hygienic macros (I'm asking about real lisp macros), so please no answers with hygienic macros.

**EDIT**:

My macro works correctly in Guile and BiwaScheme and in my own scheme like lisp in JavaScript. Here is better example:

```
(define-macro (test x)
   (if (quoted-symbol? x)
       `',(cadr x)))

(define (example arg)
  (list arg (test 'world)))

(example 'hello)
```

the question was not about `display`, but about `(cadr x)`.

**EDIT2**: You've asked so here you go, my macro:

```
(define-macro (--> expr . code)
  "Helper macro that simplify calling methods on objects. It work with chaining

   usage: (--> ($ \"body\")
               (css \"color\" \"red\")
               (on \"click\" (lambda () (print \"click\"))))

          (--> document (querySelectorAll \"div\"))

          (--> (fetch \"https://jcubic.pl\") (text) (match /<title>([^<]+)<\/title>/) 1)

          (--> document (querySelectorAll \".cmd-prompt\") 0 \"innerText\")"
  (let ((obj (gensym)))
    `(let* ((,obj ,(if (and (symbol? expr) (not (null? (match /\./ (symbol->string expr)))))
                       `(.. ,expr)
                       `,expr)))
       ,@(map (lambda (code)
                (let ((name (gensym))
                      (value (gensym)))
                  `(let* ((,name ,(cond ((quoted-symbol? code) (symbol->string (cadr code)))
                                        ((pair? code) (symbol->string (car code)))
                                        (true code)))
                          (,value (. ,obj ,name)))
                     ,(if (and (pair? code) (not (quoted-symbol? code)))
                         `(set! ,obj (,value ,@(cdr code)))
                         `(set! ,obj ,value)))))
              code)
       ,obj)))

;; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(define (quoted-symbol? x)
   "(quoted-symbol? code)

   Helper function that test if value is quoted symbol. To be used in macros
   that pass literal code that is transformed by parser.

   usage:

      (define-macro (test x)
         (if (quoted-symbol? x)
             `',(cadr x)))

      (list 'hello (test 'world))"
   (and (pair? x) (eq? (car x) 'quote) (symbol? (cadr x)) (null? (cddr x))))
```

the macro is used in my scheme like lisp in JavaScript, like the doc string suggest:

```
(--> document (querySelectorAll ".class") 0 "innerText")
```

I want to support:

```
(--> document (querySelectorAll ".class") 0 'innerText)
```

The code can be tested online at: https://jcubic.github.io/lips/ (You need to copy/paste the code since current version allow only method calls).

To get expansion you can use

```
(pprint (macroexpand (-->  document (querySelector "x"))))
```

if it don't work (don't expand) it mean that macro is broken somehow.

dot is build in function that get property of an object and `..` macro:

```
(define-macro (.. expr)
  "(.. foo.bar.baz)

   Macro that gets value from nested object where argument is comma separated symbol"
  (if (not (symbol? expr))
      expr
      (let ((parts (split "." (symbol->string expr))))
        (if (single parts)
            expr
            `(. ,(string->symbol (car parts)) ,@(cdr parts))))))
```

that can be use to get nested property like `(.. document.body.innerHTML)`

Comment: I think you should make clear what you're trying to achieve: what purpose do you have in treating quoted symbols specially?  What should the expansion be if the argument to the macro is not a quoted symbol?  This all smells strongly like an XY question.

Comment: Your last edition of the macro returns undefined when it is not a quoted symbol. Eg `(test var) ` will fail and `(test (quote var)) ` expands to `(quote var)` which then gets evaluated to the symbol `var` by scheme. What is the purpose of the identity macro? Could you come with a real problem you have?

Comment: @Sylwester I've edited my question with my code as you've requested.

Comment: I don't know enough JS to understand what the semantics of what you are trying to do is, but almost certainly the answer is not to do this in the macro: have the macro rewrite to a syntactically-less-convenient function call (or set of function calls) and then let the *functions* handle the differences between strings and symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Scheme doesn't have "real lisp macros". Some implementations has something similar, but the forms have different names and uses. They are not portable at all.

The standard way of handling `'x` is to handle it like an expression that gets evaluated in the expansion. Eg.

```
(define var 'x)

(test 'x)
(test var)
```

The two `test` forms should amount to the same even though the macro `test` gets `(quote x)` in the first and the symbol `var` in the second. At the time of the expansion `var` does not exist since the implementation can expand all the macros before starting.

You implementation of `test` will not work. Eg. the `display` might be run one or twice and then each time you call a procedure that uses it it will gfail since the expansion is the undefined value and it might not be fit for evaluation. eg.

```
(define (example arg)
  (list arg (test 'w)))
```

When this is defined you get `'w` or `(quote w)` printed with a newline and then the procedure it tries to store is:

```
(define (example arg)
  (list arg #<undefined>))
```

Note that what constitutes the undefined value is chosen by the implementaion, but I know for sure that in many implementaions you cannot evaluate `#<undefined>`.

Comment: it works correctly it's just the macro don't return anything it just prints the arguments, that's why it have `#<undefined>`, it works as expected in Guile and In biwaScheme. See my edit.